# Discard a particular set of .xml files while parsing through numerous .xml files in a particular folder in a batch script

Tags: batch-file, batch-rename

I want to write a batch script wherein it will parse through .xml files in a particular location and output the total count of a particular tag in the xml files. But in doing so, I have quite a few .xml files in the folder but I want to parse through only those .xml files that does not have the string "DEL" in the filenames.

For example,
Suppose I have the below list of xml files in a folder :

```
abc.xml     
pwrdt.xml     
terwyw.xml     
drDELyt.xml     
yrte.xml     
uyteDEL.xml     
DELytety.xml     
ahdDELwe.xml
```

I want to write a batch script which parses through only those .xml files from the above list which does not contain the string `DEL` in the file name.

So I want to parse through only,

```
abc.xml     
pwrdt.xml     
terwyw.xml     
yrte.xml
```

---

```
@echo off    
findstr /ip /c:"/ORDNUM" C:\Users\mypath\Desktop\folder\*.xml >> log-it.txt
```

In the above statement, I want to search `/ORDNUM` in only those .xml files that does NOT contain "DEL" in their file name

Below is the script I am using now :

```
@Echo off
(for /f "delims=" %%F in ('Dir /B "C:\Users\soumya.kanti.dey\Desktop\Splunk\*.xml" ^| Findstr /v "DEL" ') do (
    Echo Processing file %%F
    findstr /ip /c:"/ORDNUM" "%%F"
)) > log-it.txt

for /f "delims=: tokens=2" %%C in ('find /C "/ORDNUM" log-it.txt') Do Set /A "Count=%%C"
echo %count% > "C:\Users\soumya.kanti.dey\Desktop\total.txt"
```

Comment: Using a wildcard as input for findstr you can't exclude any files, you'll need a `for /f` to parse dir output filtered by another find/findstr /v to only process wanted xml files.

Comment: can you explain with a example please..??

Comment: What **does** the file `log-it.txt` contain after a run?

Comment: After I run the script..    
log-it.txt gets created and it contains below data..    
Processing file test.xml    
Processing file test1.xml    
Processing file test2.xml

Comment: Since you don't seem to be interested in the file names `/ORDNUM` remove the lne `Echo Processing file %%F` if there are no lines containing `/ORDNUM` are there matches at all?

Comment: yes there are matches in all the files (test.xml,test1.xml,test2.xml).......the whole purpose of this script is to count number of times "/ORDNUM" appears in total

Comment: "/ORDNUM" is basicaly one of the xml tags.. <ORDNUM>XXXXX</ORDNUM>

Comment: The file `%%F` can't be found, because it's missing it's path (`dir /b` gives only filename.extension, but no path, so `%%F` is only filename.ext and when you script isn't in that very folder, the file won't be there.

Comment: Note: `find` and `findstr` do NOT count occurences of a string, but LINES that contain the string (one or more times) - which may give wrong results.

Comment: Do a `Dir /B "C:\Users\soumya.kanti.dey\Desktop\Splunk\*.xml"` to see, that the folder is not included. So it isn't part of `%%F`, so the file "does not exist", unless you  set the working folder to that folder (`cd` or `pushd`)

Comment: that's what I said. What is your working folder (your prompt)?

Comment: It is working for me now.... HURRAY...!!!!!
I moved the location of the script to the location where the .xml files are present... and it works perfectly now...
Thank You Very Much Stephan and @LotPings

Comment: @Stephan LotPings in the 2nd for loop mentioned in the solution, what exactly is "delims=: tokens=2" is doing.... I could not find any delimiters as ":" in log-it.txt file... can you please explain what is the use of these then?

Comment: @skd:  if you do just `find /c "/ORDNUM" log-it.txt`, what's the ouput? Is there a `:`? What's the second token? (rhetorical questions - no answers expected)

Comment: there is no : in log-it.txt file..

if I just do find /c "/ORDNUM" log-it.txt I get the output as 4..
Below is the content of log-it.txt..

   <ORDNUM>L4dg66</ORDNUM>
   <ORDNUM>XE466</ORDNUM>
 <ORDNUM>KJG66</ORDNUM>
 <ORDNUM>TRE66</ORDNUM>

Comment: `dir /B /A:-D "*.xml" | findstr /R /I /V /C:"\.xml[^\.][^\.]*$" /C:"DEL.*\.xml$"` would only return `.xml` files that do not include `DEL` anywhere in their file names...

Comment: @skd: I did not say, there is a colon in the file. But there is one in the output of `find /c ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a wildcard as input for findstr you can't exclude any files, you'll need a for /f to parse dir output filtered by another find/findstr /v to only process wanted xml files.

```
@Echo off
for /f "delims=" %%F in ('Dir /B "C:\Users\mypath\Desktop\folder\*.xml" ^| Findstr /v "DEL" ') do findstr /ip /c:"/ORDNUM" "%%F" >> log-it.txt
```

As findstr doesn't output the file name when processing a single file you might use

```
@Echo off
(for /f "delims=" %%F in ('Dir /B "C:\Users\mypath\Desktop\folder\*.xml" ^| Findstr /v "DEL" ') do (
    Echo Processing file %%F
    findstr /ip /c:"/ORDNUM" "%%F"
)) > log-it.txt
```

Changed `>>` to `>` to recreate the file in each run.

To save the count of matches in file `log-it.txt` use (append)

```
for /f "delims=: tokens=2" %%C in ('find /C "/ORDNUM" log-it.txt') Do Set /A "Count=%%C"
echo %count% > "C:\Users\mypath\Desktop\total.txt"
```

Comment: I suggest to delete no longer needd comments and see the changed answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of a simple [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) attempt at this task. *It assumes that you're happy with the count of lines containing `/ORDNUMBER`, not the number of instances of it, (which is not necessarily the same)*.

```bat
@>"%UserProfile%\Desktop\total.txt" (   For /F Delims^=^ EOL^= %%A In (
        'FindStr /IMP "\/ORDNUMBER" *.xml 2^>Nul^|Find /V "DEL"'
    )Do @For /F Tokens^=1* %%B In ('Find /C "/ORDNUMBER" "%%A"')Do @Echo(%%C)
```

If the content of `total.txt` does not show what you wanted, can you please explain your overall task better.

If you only want a total for all files together, without identifying the individual filenames associated with each, you could try this, *(which doesn't use any `For` loops)*.

```bat
@(FindStr /IMP "\/ORDNUMBER" *.xml 2>Nul|Find /V "DEL"|FindStr /IF:/ "\/ORDNUMBER"|Find /V /C "")>"%UserProfile%\Desktop\total.txt"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this solution... but the previous solutions has already solved my purpose... But I will definately give a try with the solution suggested by you... Thanks again..

Comment: No problem @skd, please note that I've now added an additional example to the bottom of my answer, because I wasn't sure what you wanted in `total.txt`.